# Putting image in PDF at specified form field IN PHP

Tags: php

I have some code already that will take a PDF form and auto-populate the fields with the desired data. Now I need to be able to determine where the bounding box for a given field is and what it's dimensions are, in order to put an image file on top of that area....

I've check out Adobe Acrobat Pro, PDFtk, FPDF, PHP's PDF functions... etc. But haven't found a solution.

Any ideas on this one?

Thanx,

Answer (score 0):

You can populate your pdf files in mPDF here is a link to their website: 
http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/index.php

For your quiestion this example might be helpful since it shows how to populate invoice from scratch:
http://mpdf1.com/manual/index.php?tid=366

Result:
http://mpdf1.com/manual/files/docs/example_invoice.pdf